# How to get ContentItems with specific part in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm writing a module for Orchard and I need to know how to query the Orchard DB for ContentItems with a specific part. I want to do this in my PartDriver so I can return a SelectList with all the ContentItems present. I understand most of what I need to do except for the part where I query Orchard for the ContentItems.

Any one? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject IContentManager and Query<YourPart, YourPartRecord>